# Pack bytecode string into struct as 32-bit value

Tags: python

I need to pack an inputted value into a struct, and to pack it as a 32-bit # (unsigned int).

An example input is '\x08\x08\x08\x08'

However, this doesn't work:

```
>>> s = struct.pack('I', '\x08\x08\x08\x08')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: cannot convert argument to integer
```

What am I doing wrong? Wrapping it as int() doesn't work:

```
>>> int('\x08\x08\x08\x08', 16)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '\x08\x08\x08\x08'
```

I'm trying to build a struct that has other packed values before and after this one. For example, I want

```
inp = '\x08\x08\x08\x08'
s = struct.pack('HHIH', 50, 100, inp, 100)
```

to return

```
'2\x00d\x00\x08\x08\x08\x08d\x00'
```

Comment: Packing to `I` requires an *integer* input. Are you certain you didn't mean to *unpack* instead?

Comment: If you're on python3.2 or newer, you can use `int.from_bytes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What - *exactly* - do you want as an output?  `struct.pack()` would return (if it worked) a string exactly like the one you passed in to begin with.  `struct.unpack('I', '\x08\x08\x08\x08')` returns the tuple `(134744072,)`.  Feed that back into `struct.pack()`, and you get back the string you started with:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('I', '\x08\x08\x08\x08')
(134744072,)
>>> struct.pack('I', _[0])
'\x08\x08\x08\x08'
```

All this is working as documented and as expected.  So please clarity what it is you want instead.

> Could I just do something like struct.pack('H', somevalue) +
>   '\x08\x08\x08\x08' + struct.pack('H', someothervalue) to make
>   one big struct?

Maybe.  It depends on things you haven't spelled out, like whether or not you're using `struct` to automagically insert padding bytes (for alignment) too.  If you paste the string together yourself, then you're responsible for getting that all right.

If you decide you do want to paste a 4-byte string in, then using the `struct` format code `4s` is an easier way to do it.

Comment: Hmmm. I just want it included in my struct since I'm packing values before and after that one. Could I just do something like struct.pack('H', somevalue) + '\x08\x08\x08\x08' + struct.pack('H', someothervalue) to make one big struct?

Comment: Just a thought:  I don't know that a lot of people are aware of the `_` trick in the interactive interpretter.  I tend to not use it around here as a people might start to think that `_` has some magical properties in the *non* interactive interpretter which isn't a good thing since `_` is the conventional "unused" variable.

Comment: Please edit your question to give a *complete* (all inputs and all desired output) example of *exactly* what you want.  Don't try to describe it - show it.

Comment: @mgilson, point taken, but I do it on purpose:  it's a valuable thing to learn.  If it confuses someone, they can ask.  Learning how to ask is a valuable thing too ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters -- Fair enough.  I'm pretty sure that I've done stuff like that too at one point or another. :)

Comment: My edit overlapped with yours ;-)  As noted, use a `4s` format code instead of `I` to paste in a 4-byte string.

Answer (score 0):

The string '\x08\x08\x08\x08' is already a "packed" representation of an integer.
If you want to convert it to a python integer you should try this:

```
struct.unpack('I','\x08\x08\x08\x08')
```

Of course, pay attention to endianness.